# Store text file into memory and access it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a dictionary text file I want to store in memory DB, and then another text file I'd like to compare against the dictionary, however not sure what to use for this - has anyone used LokiJS?

I'm building the entire application in Javascript.

Could I simply use Angular to store the multi line text files and expose as JSON maybe?

I know in Node I can do it as simply as:

```
 var buffer = fs.readFileSync(filename);
```

But wondering if there is a simpler way with Angular instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the file in the `local storage` or `session storage`.

For quick implementation, use ngStorage with your Angular App.

```
angular.module('app', [
   'ngStorage'
]).controller('Ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorage,
    $sessionStorage
){
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({value: 'mysavedData'});
});
```

Let me know if you need a live demo.